# Add shadow to a UIView with layer

Tags: swift, calayer, layer, shadow, cashapelayer

I'm trying to add shadow to a view with layer and gradient. Following what i was able to realize:

1) The path

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: myView.frame.minX, y: myView.frame.minY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: myView.frame.minX, y: myView.frame.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: myView.frame.maxX, y: 171))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: myView.frame.maxX, y: myView.frame.minY))
path.close()
```

2) The shape

```
let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = path.cgPath
```

3) The gradient and shadow

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = myView.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)

let shadow = CALayer()
shadow.shadowPath = path.cgPath
shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
shadow.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

4) Put all layers as sublayer of my view

```
self.myView.layer.addSublayer(shape)
self.myView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
self.myView.layer.addSublayer(shadow)
self.myView.layer.mask = shape
```

here what simulator shows to me: what?!?! the shadows is placed on the view, not below!!!
[image]

What could I do to fix it? my final purpose is to put the shadow below the view (as the red line).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

3) Set the shape as a mask to the gradient. Set shadow to `myView.layer`

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = myView.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
gradient.mask = shape // <-- 1

let shadow = myView.layer // <-- 2
shadow.shadowPath = path.cgPath
shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
shadow.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

4) Just put the gradient as a sublayer of `myView.layer`

```
self.myView.layer.addSublayer(gradient) // <-- 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the shadow radius as well.

```
shadow.shadowRadius = 5
```

Comment: I forgot to assign the shadow radius, but the shadow is not yet fixed even by doing so

Comment: try with
shadow.maskToBounds = false

Comment: remove this line..   
self.myView.layer.mask = shape

Comment: nope... the shadow is jet superimposed to the view, but this time is cut as the shape...